Change the bound v-model by changing the value in the input
I am trying to implement an on-screen keyboard for entering numbers into various input fields. In a real project, there are several dozen of them. I save the active field through focus and when I click on a number, it is added to the end of the field value. But when I change the value of the input, the value of the bound v-model does not change. Although, when I enter from a regular keyboard, everything changes normally. I am attaching the example code
<template>
    <p>xSize</p>
    <input v-model="xSize">
    <p>ySize</p>
    <input v-model="ySize">
    <div class="keyboard">
        <button v-for="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]" class="key" :key="i" @click="addChar(i)">{{i}}</button>
    </div>
    <p>xSize = {{xSize}}</p>
    <p>ySize = {{ySize}}</p>
    <div class="test-box" v-bind:style="{width: this.xSize + 'px', height: this.ySize + 'px'}"></div>


</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      xSize: 50,
      ySize: 50,
      activeElement: null
    }
  },
  props: {

  },
  created() {
    document.addEventListener('focusin', this.focusChanged)
  },
  beforeUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('focusin', this.focusChanged)
  },
  methods: {
    focusChanged: function (event) {
      const el = event.target
      if (el.type === "text") {
        if (this.activeElement !== el && this.activeElement !== null) {
          this.activeElement.style.background = "white";
        }

        this.activeElement = el
        this.activeElement.style.background = "red";
      }
    },
    addChar: function (char) {
      if (this.activeElement !== null) {
        this.activeElement.value += char
      }
    }

  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
    .keyboard {
      display: flex;
    }
    .key {
      margin: 3px;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      border: 2px black ridge;
    }

    .test-box {
      border: 2px black ridge;
      background: red;
      margin: 15px;
    }
</style>


Example

Because what you modified was only the value of the element, not the responsive data in the data.
You can change the code to this way.
<template>
    <p>xSize</p>
    <input v-model="xSize" data-name="xSize">
    <p>ySize</p>
    <input v-model="ySize" data-name="ySize">
    <div class="keyboard">
        <button v-for="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]" class="key" :key="i" @click="addChar(i)">{{i}}</button>
    </div>
    <p>xSize = {{xSize}}</p>
    <p>ySize = {{ySize}}</p>
    <div class="test-box" v-bind:style="{width: this.xSize + 'px', height: this.ySize + 'px'}"></div>


</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      xSize: 50,
      ySize: 50,
      activeElement: null
    }
  },
  props: {

  },
  created() {
    document.addEventListener('focusin', this.focusChanged)
  },
  beforeUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('focusin', this.focusChanged)
  },
  methods: {
    focusChanged: function (event) {
      const el = event.target
      if (el.type === "text") {
        if (this.activeElement !== el && this.activeElement !== null) {
          this.activeElement.style.background = "white";
        }

        this.activeElement = el
        this.activeElement.style.background = "red";
      }
    },
    addChar: function (char) {
      if (this.activeElement !== null) {
        const fieldName = this.activeElement.getAttribute("data-name");
        this[fieldName] += char
      }
    }

  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
    .keyboard {
      display: flex;
    }
    .key {
      margin: 3px;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      border: 2px black ridge;
    }

    .test-box {
      border: 2px black ridge;
      background: red;
      margin: 15px;
    }
</style>


Yes, your solution helped me. Many thanks for the help!

Take a look at the following example please (You can use @focus event and convert code to options api if You like that way :))


const { ref, computed } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const xSize = ref(50)
    const ySize = ref(50)
    const activeElement = ref('x')
    const operation = ref('+')
    const isActive = (el) => {
      return activeElement.value === el ? 'active' : ''
    }
    const addChar = (char) => {
      if (operation.value === '+') {
        activeElement.value === 'x' ?
          xSize.value = +xSize.value + char :
          ySize.value = +ySize.value + char
      } else {
        activeElement.value === 'x' ?
          xSize.value = +xSize.value >= +char ? +xSize.value - char : +xSize.value :
          ySize.value = +ySize.value >= +char ? +ySize.value - char : +ySize.value
      }
    }
    const setSize = computed(() => {
      return {
        width: xSize.value + 'px',
        height: ySize.value + 'px'
      }
    })
    return {
      xSize, ySize, activeElement, addChar, isActive, operation, setSize
    }
  },
})
app.mount("#demo");
.keyboard {
  display: flex;
}
.key {
  margin: 3px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px black ridge;
}
.test-box {
  border: 2px black ridge;
  background: red;
  margin: 15px;
}
.active {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div>
    <span>xSize </span>
    <input v-model="xSize" :class="isActive('x')" @focus="activeElement = 'x'">
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>ySize </span>
    <input v-model="ySize" :class="isActive('y')" @focus="activeElement = 'y'">
  </div>
  <div class="keyboard">
    <button @click="operation = operation === '+' ? '-' : '+'" class="key">{{ operation }}</button>
    <button v-for="i in 10" class="key" :key="i" @click="addChar(i)">{{ i }}</button>
  </div>
  <div class="test-box" :style="setSize"></div>
</div>




Thanks for the answer. To be honest, I would like to avoid this solution, since in a real project it would lead to a very large "switch case" construct.

try i check something like:
<input v-model="xSize" @input="updateSize('xSize', $event.target.value)">

@input event on the input fields to ensure that any change to the input value is captured and handled by the updateSize method,
the updateSize method is called with the appropriate size type (xSize or ySize) and the new value. This method updates the appropriate property in the Vue instance.


Thanks for the answer. Alas, the @input event does not fire when pressing keys

Because what you modified was only the value of the element, not the responsive data in the data.

I understand it. The question is whether it is possible to somehow change this adaptive data through the element. Or in event click access adaptive data.

Centainly. I added the code in another answer, you can take a look.
